# Can't stream video

Tags: streaming-video, webcam

I have a Pi 3 model B Rev 1.2 and I would like to use it as a surveillance camera server.
There seems to be no stream at all. I don't know if the cam isn't working (it works on my ubuntu workstation) or if motion hasn't been configured correctly.

I have tried many "how to"s but all fail. Some of them because they were out of date but the [last one](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-security-camera-livestream-setup/) I tried seems to be up to date but still fails.
Here is the url:

https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/raspberry-pi-security-camera-livestream-setup/

When I test the stream, either on Firefox or on VLC, the stream is not available:
Firefox: Unable to connect,
VLC: Seee below for log excerpt.

My webcam led turns on for a fraction of a second then turns off when I plug it in, but does nothing when I start the daemon. It seems not to be working, yet it is detected (Bus 001 Device 006):

```
ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video10  /dev/video11  /dev/video12
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 6901:2701  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:075d Microsoft Corp. LifeCam Cinema
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet
Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Some tests results as suggested by the author of the page:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video10  /dev/video11  /dev/video12
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl -V
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 640/480
    Pixel Format      : 'YUYV'
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 1280
    Size Image        : 156273376
    Colorspace        : sRGB
    Transfer Function : Default
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default
    Quantization      : Default
    Flags             :
```

VLC log:

```
http debug: resolving 192.168.1.8 ...
http debug: outgoing request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.8:8081
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en_US
User-Agent: VLC/3.0.8 LibVLC/3.0.8
Range: bytes=0-


http debug: connection failed
access error: HTTP connection failure
http debug: querying proxy for http://192.168.1.8:8081
http debug: no proxy
http debug: http: server='192.168.1.8' port=8081 file=''
main debug: net: connecting to 192.168.1.8 port 8081
main error: connection failed: Connection refused
http error: cannot connect to 192.168.1.8:8081
main debug: no access modules matched
main debug: dead input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
main debug: nothing to play
```

Motion status:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service motion status
* motion.service - LSB: Start Motion detection
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/motion; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2020-03-09 20:38:13 EDT; 20h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 544 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/motion start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/motion.service

Mar 09 20:38:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Motion detection...
Mar 09 20:38:13 raspberrypi motion[544]: Starting motion detection daemon: motion.
Mar 09 20:38:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Motion detection.
```

syslog:

```
Mar 10 17:02:21 raspberrypi systemd[634]: Time has been changed
Mar 10 17:02:21 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[284]: Synchronized to time server 200.160.7.186:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Mar 10 17:02:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Mar 10 17:02:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Mar 10 17:02:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Mar 10 17:02:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 2h 39min 18.757727s random time.
Mar 10 17:02:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 1h 47min 32.027613s random time.
Mar 10 17:02:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Mar 10 17:02:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Mar 10 17:02:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 10.491242s random time.
Mar 10 17:02:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 2min 16.903869s random time.
Mar 10 17:02:43 raspberrypi kernel: [   57.069307] random: crng init done
Mar 10 17:02:43 raspberrypi kernel: [   57.069319] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
Mar 10 17:02:43 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[537,root]: ServerManager: Server started
Mar 10 17:02:43 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[537,root]: ConsoleDisplay: Found running X server (pid=598, binary=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg)
```

Comment: What does syslog say : sudo tail /var/log/syslog ? Are you sure `192.168.1.8` exists on your LAN and his port `8081` is opened ?

Comment: @Ephemeral: Yes, I connect via ssh with this ip. As for the opne port, I ran this command and it seems to be shut: nc -zvw3 192.168.1.8 8081
nc: connect to 192.168.1.8 port 8081 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

Comment: @Epehemeral: I haven't found any running firewall. I don't know what could be blocking the connection.

Comment: My camera works when view through remote desktop, so it is not a problem with the camera.

Comment: My camera seems not to be running e.g. the led that stays off.

Comment: `My webcam led turns on for a fraction of a second then turns off`, because your camera is probably open BEFORE the network connection and because the connection failed, the program stop and the camera is closed.

Comment: In `/etc/motion/motion.conf` have you put the correct value specified in the tutorial : `stream_localhost off` and `daemon on` ? Try this command when you run your server : `sudo netstat -laputen | grep ":8081"`, what is the output of this command ? You must have : `0.0.0.0` or `192.168.1.8` in your output if the daemon is correctly running.

Comment: To run your daemon: `sudo service motion start`, and try to reconnect. If this fails, try: `sudo service motion status` and put the output by editing your question. And also put your `/etc/motion/motion.conf` file content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105418/discussion-between-frepie-and-ephemeral).